# How to get parameter from one function to another function in the same controller laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

How can I get parameter from controller 1 to controller 2. My controller 1 is return view and controller 2 is angular. How can I get branchid from controller 1 to controller 2?

I use this code for my route:

```
Route::get('srccond/{branchid}', 'ShowstaffController@return_view');
Route::get('/api/v1/srcs/', 'ShowstaffController@searchcond');
```

my view for `srccond route`

```
<a href="{{url('srccond/'.$value->branch_id)}}" class="brnch_clk" 
data-branch="{{$value->branch_id}}">{{$value->branch_name}}</a>
```

My controller

```
public function return_view($branchid){
        $data_branch_dep = DB::table('branch_tbl')->orderby('branch_name')->get();
        $data_dep = DB::table('dep_tbl')->orderby('dep_name')->get();

        return view('frontend.staffinfoajax', compact('data_branch_dep', 'data_dep'));
    }

    public function searchcond(){

        return DB::table('studentinfo')->where('branchID', '=', $branchid)->get();
    }
```

How can I get `$branchid` from `function return_view` to `function searchcond`?

Answer (score 1):

Well do it like this

```
resolve(ShowstaffController::class)->return_view();
```

But I would recommend making a new function rather than using this one since this one is returning a view.

If you want to use the same function then you can pass a parameter to it which can tell either to return a view or variable

Comment: well you place it in place of `$branchid` in searchcond function

Comment: Got error: Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\ShowstaffController::return_view(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet\app\Http\Controllers\ShowstaffController.php on line 58 and defined

Comment: @TheRock since that is receiving a value.

Comment: @TheRock If you want it to work you will need to pass something to it

BUT KEEP ONE THING IN MIND RETURN_VIEW WILL ALWAYS RETURN A VIEW RIGHT NOW

Comment: what is on line number 58

Comment: return DB::table('studentinfo')->where('branchID', '=', resolve(ShowstaffController::class)->return_view())->get();

Comment: because return view is returning a view not a value

Comment: how can i fix this??

Comment: @TheRock you need to return a value for this to work from return_view function

Comment: From where are you getting the branchId in the return view function

Comment: You see my code in my question i return view in return_view function how can i return value??

Comment: @TheRock there are two ways that I know of 

One is you make a new function and that return a value 

and the second way is you start sending a value if it's undefined return a view other wise return a value

Comment: and one more thing you are passing branchId to return view function. can you tell me from where are you passing it